# cURL Timeout via browser

Tags: php, apache, curl

I have a very weird situation. I have third party resource url which i am accessing through cURL. I am utilizing the same class from terminal and browser. It is working fine on terminal but I get error number 28 (timeout) when I access the same url and class from browser request via ajaxd.

I spent two days to debug but couldn't find anything. 
What could be the problem?

UPDATE:
Following is the code:

```
$this->headers = [
  "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
  "Accept: text/xml",
  "Cache-Control: no-cache",
  "Pragma: no-cache",
   "Authorization: Basic c29hdXNlcjpzb2F1c2VyMTIz",
   "SOAPAction: \"getTenantUnitDetails\"",
 ];

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->soapUrl);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->requestBody); // the SOAP request
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers);

 $ch_response = curl_exec($ch);

 if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    print "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
}

return $ch_response;
```

UPDATE 2:
Here is the request from the browser which is not working.
[image]

Here is the request from terminal which is working.
[image]

Comment: Sharing the code will help us to help you.

Comment: @vivek_23 code added.

Comment: ok, so request comes from ajax -> PHP class -> soapUrl and returns like soapUrl(their server) -> PHP class -> ajax response. Am I correct?

Comment: @vivek_23 yes that is correct.

Comment: maybe the php "maximum execution time" is 30 secs (default value) and this stop the script. If this is the problem, you need to change this value. You can check http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: @juanbits that is not the problem.

Comment: @galactic.nucleus Sidenote: Since you are using basic authentication, why not just do `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $some_string. ":" . $some_other_string);` instead of `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);` ? Also, can you check in your network tab of your browser as to what response you are getting? Can you share your ajax code as well?

Comment: How did you determine that `maximum execution time` isn't the problem? Please share what you've done to debug the issue and what you've tried.

Comment: screenshots added.

Comment: @vivek_23 the ajax request gets through successfully.

Comment: The timeout is exactly the one you set in the curl options `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);`, so the ajax is not exactly getting through successfully... but it's not clear IF the requests are the same on both channels. Also, for example, try running the same curl for a different resource with no basic auth and check how it behaves.

Comment: Maybe there is a firewall interfering and your local machine is whitelisted but your server is not? Somewhat likely if it's an internal/company API.

Comment: @galactic.nucleus How much does a cURL request usually take anyway when you run through terminal?

Comment: @vivek_23 fraction of a second.

Comment: @galactic.nucleus Can you just make a cURL hit to Google.com via PHP and see if it still times out in Ajax request?